# RST cross referencing not working in code highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting, highlight, restructuredtext, cross-reference, docutils

I use docutils in order to produce documents via rst file.

In my document, I need to add and highlight some source code. Also I use cross referencing to make some keywords (section names) hyperlink to the respective section. So, simply append an underline to the end of the word, e.g `mysection_` which refers to:

```
mysection
---------

Some text...
```

The problem occurs when I use the format of code highlighting. That is, if I use `.. code:: C` and then a block of C code, cross referencing in the source code does not work:

```c
.. code:: C

    #include "example.h"
    int main()
    {
        printf("My Section is:");
        mysection_();
        return 0;    
    }
```

So, how can I have both *code highlighting* and *cross referencing*?

**Update:**

The same situation might happen also in Stackoverflow. When you put a code in a block of code sample, then some features like referencing are disabled! Is there any solution to enable referencing in a code sample?

For example in the following, referencing does not work:

```c
# This hello world example was copied from [C-HowTo website][1]
# As you noticed, links do not work here, but you see below code block,
# the same link works.
# Also link to [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) does not work!

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

[C-HowTo website](http://www.c-howto.de/tutorial-einfuehrung-hello-world.html)

[Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com)